# Estimating the missmatch rate on the rows in a matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix

I want to estimate rates of the values distributed apart from the diagonal in a row. However, I couldn't make my function work.

So a hypothetical data seems like:

```
tree = data.frame(Oak = c(10,1,3), Pine = c(2,15,1), Maple = c(1,1,20), 
+                   row.names = c("Oak","Pine","Maple"))
> tree 
         Oak Pine Maple
  Oak     10    2     1
  Pine     1   15     1
  Maple    3    1    20
```

Let's say for Oak, I want to get the value: (2 + 1) / (10 + 2 + 1) = 0.2308 which is "taking the values where the row name and the column name aren't the same"/ "sum of the row"

And I also want repeat this operation for all of the columns. I thought that to write down a function, especially for the big real datasets would be better.

So I came up this function:

```
miss.rate = function(data) {
rate.x = sum(data[(data["i",] != data[,"i"]),])/
(sum(data["i",]))
data.frame(tree = "i", rate  = rate.x)
}
```

However, it didn't work as I expected and I don't get where it goes wrong.

My expected output for the function was:

```
tree  rate
Oak   0.2308
Pine  0.1176
Maple 0.1667
```

Suggestions would be great?

Comment: `2 + 1 / 10 + 2 + 1 != 0.2143`

Comment: Corrected! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or an one-liner:

```
1 - diag(as.matrix(tree)) / rowSums(tree)
#       Oak      Pine     Maple 
# 0.2307692 0.1176471 0.1666667
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot but I wanted to implement in a function in order to use in multiple datasets at the same time.

Comment: Well, turn the above expression into a function: `miss_rate <- function(tree) 1 - diag(as.matrix(tree)) / rowSums(tree)`

Answer (score 0):

```
t(
sapply(seq_along(tree), function(x) { data.frame(tree = I(names(tree)[x]), rate = sum(tree[x,-x]) / sum(tree[x,])) })
)

#     tree    rate     
#[1,] "Oak"   0.2307692
#[2,] "Pine"  0.1176471
#[3,] "Maple" 0.1666667
```